# Implementing anonymous functions in Fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran, anonymous-function

This question is successor of my previous question [Implementing minimization method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633007/implementing-minimization-method). In current question, I simplified my problem and here is the sample MATLAB code. I want to implement it in Fortran.

```
%Script script1.m 
clear vars;
close all;
clc;

fun1 = @(x1,x2) 3*x1^2 + 4*x2^2 + 5*x1 + 6*x2 + 10;

lower = -2;
upper = 0;
fun5 = fun15(fun1);
%fun5 is 'intermediate' function

%calling minimization function
[location,value]=minimize1(fun5,lower,upper)
```

In the script1.m, I created a function handle `fun1` and want to assign values to it as shown in the `fun15.m`

```
%fun15.m
function fun2 = fun15( fun1 )
arr1 = [4,5];
arr2 = [-2,3];
fun2 = @(a) fun1( ( arr1(1) + a*arr2(1)) , ( arr1(2) + a*arr2(2)));
%fun2 = @(a) @(x4,y4,x5,y5)  3*(x4+a*x5)^2 + 4*(y4+a*y5)^2 + 5*(x4+a*x5) + 6*(y4+a*y5) + 10; .....(1)
end
```

Instead of file fun15.m, it is quite possible to create a closure as shown by (1). Here, `arr1 = [x4,y4]` and `arr2=[x5,y5]`. We can first pass values of `x4,y4,x5,y5` and it will return a function in variable `a`. This returned function is passed to a minimization function below.

```
%minimize1.m
function [loc,val] = minimize1 (fun1,lower,upper)
c1 = 1; %counter
x_1 = lower + (upper-lower)*0.382; %lower value
x_2 = lower + (upper-lower)*0.618; %upper value
f_1 = fun1(x_1); %fun1 is passed in the arguments
f_2 = fun1(x_2);
x_lower=lower;
x_upper=upper;
locx=0;

   while c1<10

        if (f_1 > f_2) 
            x_lower = x_1;
            x_1=x_2;
            f_1=f_2;
            x_2 = x_lower + (x_upper-x_lower)*0.618;
            f_2 = fun1(x_2);
        else
            x_upper = x_2;
            x_2 = x_1;
            f_2 = f_1;
            x_1 = x_lower + (x_upper-x_lower)*0.382;
            f_1 = fun1(x_1);
        end

        c1=c1+1;
   end
locx=(x_lower + x_upper)/2.0;
val = fun1(locx);

end
```

How to convert this into Fortran - especially function returning function? [Anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) functions are not supported by Fortran (C++11 supports it as lambdas, and ALGOL 68 as well). Is it possible to implement this  problem in Modern Fortran (90,95,03,08)?

Comment: What version of Fortran are you using. You can pass pointers to procedures in more recent standards (Fortran 2003 onwards I believe)

Comment: @s8129 Correct, you can pass function into another function by function  pointer or creating an interface (or using `external` in old fortran). But how to get a function output from a function seems bigger problem.

Comment: @VladimirF I agree with roygvib, the 'original' question does not discuss full code. In this question, I have full and specific code, also describe closure. The other question does not have anything like that. Stackoverflow should not be a place to find out similarities between every question and mark every possible duplicate. Mainly, note the answer provided to this question and other other. A person reading this question will certainly benefit by the detailed code provided by IanH. The depth of the other question and answer cannot match depth of this QA.

Comment: In my opinion this is as exact duplicate as it gets. Even Ian's answer begins with two points exactly matching those two answers. BTW why didn't you accept the answer yet when you apparently like it?  Please understand that closing is **not deleting** at all it is more about linking them so the next person seeking help gets all what's here. For Ian it is an adcantage, because noone can compete with his answer here. Also he can always add an answer this detailed to the old question.

Comment: There vere actually many questions about this problem before, some even discuss saving closures, tje functor pattern and so one. I believe there are maybe 10 very similar questions to yours here and I believe they should be linked together. But I am not the only one onewho can do this here. Notice there has not ben a single reopen vote placed to this question yet.

Comment: @roygvib You are encourage to to comment about obselete answers, downvote them to bring attention to them, edit them with a disclaimer that they are obsolete, place new answers to the questions. It more useful if people arrive to the question they most often arrive and find a new answer then having to search if somone asked the same and got more recent answer.

Comment: @roygvib 1. I don't always remeber or find the duplpicate, you are more then welcome to bring attention to it by voting or commenting. 2. Anyone with with rep above 3000 is able to vote for re-opening this question right now! There is not a single reopen vote yet here.

Comment: Similar (duplicate?) questions. Please don't delete this comment, serves for linking them together on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391991/in-fortran-90-how-do-i-program-the-equivalent-of-a-handle-in-matlab?noredirect=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127313/passing-external-function-of-multiple-variables-as-a-function-of-one-variable-in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692697/fortran-90-dynamic-function-creation-from-another-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208594/how-to-pass-a-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-a-subroutine-that-expects-a-fu   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982657/passing-an-internal-procedure-as-argument More about closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471640/fortran-return-an-anonymous-function-from-subroutine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675891/function-as-an-output-argument/19675970

Comment: @roygvib My usual rule which I have from the meta.stackoverflow.com  discussions  is if I  can easily answer by copying the answer from an older question, it is probably a duplicate. I certainly could have done this. It is not selfish, I am actually denying rep for me, Search in the list above how many times I could have quickly placed an answer by Ctrl+C Ctrl+V but I didn't. It is to keep the questions pointing to a single place.

Comment: @VladimirF  "BTW why didn't you accept the answer yet when you apparently like it?" I am waiting for some more time. Accepting answer asap someone posts one discourage further answers, which may be better. At least I personally think like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fortran doesn't support anonymous functions.  The simple work around is to write a function that has a name.

There are then two possible approaches in modern Fortran for capturing the value of any additional parameters required for the function beyond the variable being minimised:

- The procedure to be minimised is expressed as a deferred binding of an abstract type (a functor type), with the additional parameters for the underlying function available as components of concrete extensions of the abstract type.  If necessary one of the components can be a procedure pointer or another object of a functor type.
- The procedure to be minimised is an internal (F2008) or module procedure, with the additional parameters provided by host association.

What's best depends on specific circumstances.

Examples of both approaches are in the following.

```
MODULE Minimizer
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER, PUBLIC :: rk = KIND(1.0)

  PUBLIC :: MinimizeFunctor
  PUBLIC :: MinimizeProcedure

  TYPE, PUBLIC, ABSTRACT :: Functor
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE(functor_Evaluate), DEFERRED :: Evaluate
  END TYPE Functor

  ABSTRACT INTERFACE
    FUNCTION functor_Evaluate(obj, x)
      IMPORT :: Functor
      IMPORT :: rk
      IMPLICIT NONE
      CLASS(Functor), INTENT(IN) :: obj
      REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x
      REAL(rk) :: functor_Evaluate
    END FUNCTION functor_Evaluate
  END INTERFACE
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE MinimizeFunctor(fun, lower, upper, location, value)
    CLASS(functor), INTENT(IN) :: fun
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: lower
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: upper
    REAL(rk), INTENT(OUT) :: location
    REAL(rk), INTENT(OUT) :: value

    INTEGER :: c1
    REAL(rk) :: x_1
    REAL(rk) :: x_2
    REAL(rk) :: f_1
    REAL(rk) :: f_2
    REAL(rk) :: x_lower
    REAL(rk) :: x_upper

    c1 = 1
    x_lower = lower
    x_upper = upper
    f_1 = fun%Evaluate(x_1)
    f_2 = fun%Evaluate(x_2)
    location = 0

    DO WHILE (c1 < 10)
      IF (f_1 > f_2) THEN
        x_lower = x_1
        x_1 = x_2
        f_1 = f_2
        x_2 = x_lower + (x_upper - x_lower) * 0.618_rk
        f_2 = fun%Evaluate(x_2)
      ELSE
        x_upper = x_2
        x_2 = x_1
        f_2 = f_1
        x_1 = x_lower + (x_upper - x_lower) * 0.382_rk
        f_1 = fun%Evaluate(x_1)
      END IF
      c1 = c1 + 1
    END DO

    location = (x_Lower + x_upper) / 2.0
    value = fun%Evaluate(location)
  END SUBROUTINE MinimizeFunctor


  SUBROUTINE MinimizeProcedure(fun, lower, upper, location, value)
    INTERFACE
      FUNCTION fun(x)
        IMPORT :: rk
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x
        REAL(rk) :: fun
      END FUNCTION fun
    END INTERFACE
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: lower
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: upper
    REAL(rk), INTENT(OUT) :: location
    REAL(rk), INTENT(OUT) :: value

    INTEGER :: c1
    REAL(rk) :: x_1
    REAL(rk) :: x_2
    REAL(rk) :: f_1
    REAL(rk) :: f_2
    REAL(rk) :: x_lower
    REAL(rk) :: x_upper

    c1 = 1
    x_lower = lower
    x_upper = upper
    f_1 = fun(x_1)
    f_2 = fun(x_2)
    location = 0

    DO WHILE (c1 < 10)
      IF (f_1 > f_2) THEN
        x_lower = x_1
        x_1 = x_2
        f_1 = f_2
        x_2 = x_lower + (x_upper - x_lower) * 0.618_rk
        f_2 = fun(x_2)
      ELSE
        x_upper = x_2
        x_2 = x_1
        f_2 = f_1
        x_1 = x_lower + (x_upper - x_lower) * 0.382_rk
        f_1 = fun(x_1)
      END IF
      c1 = c1 + 1
    END DO

    location = (x_Lower + x_upper) / 2.0
    value = fun(location)
  END SUBROUTINE MinimizeProcedure
END MODULE Minimizer

MODULE m
  USE Minimizer
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE

  PUBLIC :: RunFunctor
  PUBLIC :: RunProcedure

  TYPE, EXTENDS(Functor) :: MyFunctor
    PROCEDURE(fun_ptr_intf), POINTER, NOPASS :: fun_ptr
    INTEGER :: arr1(2)
    INTEGER :: arr2(2)
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: Evaluate
  END TYPE MyFunctor

  ABSTRACT INTERFACE
    FUNCTION fun_ptr_intf(x1, x2)
      IMPORT :: rk
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x1
      REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x2
      REAL(rk) :: fun_ptr_intf
    END FUNCTION fun_ptr_intf
  END INTERFACE
CONTAINS
  FUNCTION Evaluate(obj, x)
    CLASS(MyFunctor), INTENT(IN) :: obj
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x
    REAL(rk) :: Evaluate

    Evaluate = obj%fun_ptr(  &
        obj%arr1(1) + x * obj%arr2(1),  &
        obj%arr1(2) + x * obj%arr2(2) )
  END FUNCTION Evaluate

  FUNCTION fun1(x1, x2)
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x1
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x2
    REAL(rk) :: fun1

    fun1 = 3 * x1**2 + 4 * x2**2 + 5 * x1 + 6 * x2 + 10.0_rk
  END FUNCTION fun1

  SUBROUTINE RunFunctor
    TYPE(MyFunctor) :: obj
    REAL(rk) :: location
    REAL(rk) :: value

    obj%fun_ptr => fun1

    obj%arr1 = [ 4, 5]
    obj%arr2 = [-2, 3]
    CALL MinimizeFunctor(obj, 0.0_rk, 1.0_rk, location, value)
    PRINT *, location, value
  END SUBROUTINE RunFunctor

  SUBROUTINE RunProcedure
    REAL(rk) :: location
    REAL(rk) :: value
    INTEGER :: arr1(2)
    INTEGER :: arr2(2)

    arr1 = [ 4, 5]
    arr2 = [-2, 3]
    CALL MinimizeProcedure(fun, 0.0_rk, 1.0_rk, location, value)
    PRINT *, location, value
  CONTAINS
    FUNCTION fun(x)
      REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x
      REAL(rk) :: fun

      fun = fun1(  &
          arr1(1) + x * arr2(1),  &
          arr1(2) + x * arr2(2) )
    END FUNCTION fun
  END SUBROUTINE RunProcedure
END MODULE m

PROGRAM p
  USE m
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CALL RunFunctor
  CALL RunProcedure
END PROGRAM p
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. If we compare MATLAB and Fortran code, MATLAB code is short, clear, and easy. On the other hand Fortran code is much more involved and need advanced features. Probably this is one of the reasons of declining use of Fortran in newly developed scientific software.

Comment: @de23edced I am very familiar with both.  They are markedly different tools, that have strengths and weaknesses in different areas.  What's best will depend on circumstances.  Bear in mind that the example Fortran code shows two different approaches to the problem, and what you consider an "advanced" feature across the two languages is rather subjective.  BTW your "short, clear and easy" Matlab code has a bug - there are some benefits to having explicit variable declarations!!

Answer (score 3):

By popular demand this is not an *exact* duplicate and I can therefore shamelessly reuse my former material.

You are asking about anonymous functions, but what you want to actually do is to pass a slightly modified function to a minimazation procedure. You normally don't want to emulate function objects for that ([Fortran minimization of a function with additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297170/fortran-minimization-of-a-function-with-additional-arguments))

1.
The simplest way of passing such a procedure is by using an **internal procedure**:

```
subroutine outer(fun1)
  use minimization, only: minimize
  interface
    real function fun1(x,y)
      real, intent(in) :: x, y
    end function
  end interface

  real, dimension(2) :: arr1, arr2

  arr1=...; arr2=...

  call minimize(fun2)

contains

  real function fun2(a)
    real, intent(in) :: a
    fun2 = fun1( ( arr1(1) + a*arr2(1)) , ( arr1(2) + a*arr2(2)))
  end function
end subroutine
```

note: passing internal procedures and pointers to them requires Fortran 2008.

2. You can do the same with **module procedures** too, I leave it as an exercise for the reader, just define the context (`arr1`,`arr2`) and the minimized function `fun2` not locally, but in a module. It is less flexible.

---

Now to closures:

Even in C++98 you could use a **function object** or **functor** to store the context of a function pointer to create a lexical closure. It is just a class which stores the captured context in its member variables. C++11 doesn't do anything else than just providing a syntactic sugar for such a class.

You can make a functor in Fortran, see [Dynamic function creation from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692697/dynamic-function-creation-from-another-function) , [Function as an output argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675891/function-as-an-output-argument/19675970) and [Fortran - Return an anonymous function from subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471640/fortran-return-an-anonymous-function-from-subroutine) but I consider it being way too awkward for your purpose.